# File history in git for local working copy

Tags: git

IS there any option to get file(not yet committed) changes history for working copy in git?

Because I've lost my local changes in one file in linux OS. Is there way to get by lost change again ? I've edited that file with vi command.

Answer (score 1):

If changes have not been committed (i.e., through *git commit*) or added to the index (e.g., through *git add*), then git cannot know anything about the changes you have made, and they are unfortunately lost.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any option in linux OS ? do you know ?

Comment: @ParthibanErusappan not really, no, unless you have a filesystem that keeps multiple versions of files automatically. If you don't know that you do, you don't. Sorry. In the future, consider making commits more frequently so that you lose less work. As long as you don't publish (e.g. push) commits, you can still rework them to make them nicer/cleaner, so you lose nothing by committing more often.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `reflog`. It can help.